# Get a count of the duplicates in a GenericList

Tags: powershell, duplicates, generic-list

I seem to have the darnedest time understanding predicates in .NET methods used in PowerShell. Given...

```
$list = [System.Collections.Generic.List[string]]::new()
$list.AddRange([System.Collections.Generic.List[string]]@('1', '2', '3', '2', '1', '1'))
```

I thought `$list.FindAll({$PSItem -match '1'})` would work, but no.
For what it's worth, the goal is to get a count of all the duplicates. I can find the duplicates like this

```
$duplicates = Compare-Object $list ($list | Select-Object -Unique) | 
              Where-Object SideIndicator -eq '<=' | 
              Select-Object -ExpandProperty InputObject
```

But when I try to get the count like this

```
$duplicates.Where({$PSItem -match '1'}).Count
```

I am off by one. I am thinking that is because `Compare-Object` is comparing the full list to the unique list, which is just 1,2,3 and not counting the first one as a duplicate? So `.Count+1` would be an option?

Anyway, two questions really. What does my predicate need to be for `.FindAll()`? And is `.Count+1` the best approach if using the `Compare-Object` approach?

To some extent I am trying to understand my options that don't involve the pipeline, but when there is no alternative using the pipeline is OK.

EDIT: So, a little more searching led me to add a Group-Object to get counts in `$duplicates`, then a Sort-Object since Group-Object is default sorted on the count. So, this gets me the ultimate output I want.

```
$duplicates = Compare-Object $list ($list | Select-Object -Unique) | 
              Where-Object SideIndicator -eq '<=' | 
              Select-Object -ExpandProperty InputObject |
              Group-Object -noelement |
              Sort-Object  -Property Name
$duplicatesForLog = $duplicates.Foreach({"$($PSItem.Name)($($PSItem.Count+1))"})
$duplicatesForLog -join ', '
```

Comment: You can use `Group-Object` instead. `($list | Group-Object | ? Name -eq '1').Count`.

Comment: @abraham-zinala I need to look at that approach too. I managed to get the `$duplicates` variable to include the counts, which helps. My example wasn't great, because I showed looking for count of a particular value, where what I really need is to show all duplicates and counts in a log, and the values will be unknown to me in advance.

Comment: You're overcomplicating your ```$list``` initialisation - you create an empty strongly-typed list so you can add some items, but the items you add are already *in* another instance of the same strongly-typed list - you could just say ```$list = [System.Collections.Generic.List[string]]@('1', '2', '3', '2', '1', '1')``` and get the same result :-)

Comment: @mclayton Yeah, good call. I had copied that snipped from a scenario where I was getting an array that I add to the list, so I was casting to make that work. Totally not needed for this little example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Abraham Zinala](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14903754/abraham-zinala) correctly points out that [`Group-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/group-object) is sufficient to find duplicates:

```
(
  $list |
    Group-Object |
    Where-Object Count -gt 1 |
    ForEach-Object { '{0}({1})' -f $_.Name, $_.Count }
) -join ', '
```

As for:

> What does my predicate need to be for `.FindAll()`

[`.FindAll()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.Generic.List-1.FindAll) - unlike the [*intrinsic* `.Where()` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Arrays#where) - is a *type-native* method of [`` System.Collections.Generic.List`1 ``](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.Generic.List-1), which knows nothing about *pipeline*-related automatic PowerShell variables such as `$_` aka `$PSItem`.

The script block that is being used as a [`System.Predicate[string]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Predicate-1) instance in this case receives its argument - each element of the list - as an *argument*. As usual, you can refer to this argument via the [automatic `$args` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#args) or by formally *declaring a parameter* to bind the argument to. Thus, the following two solutions are equivalent:

```
[System.Collections.Generic.List[string]] $list = @('1', '2', '3', '2', '1', '1')

# Use $args
$list.FindAll({ $args -eq '1' })

# Use a declared parameter
$list.FindAll({ param([string] $obj) $obj -eq '1' })
```

Both `.FindAll()` calls return `[System.Collections.Generic.List[string]] (1, 1, 1)`

Comment: Ah, I see how Group-Object does the job now. MUCH better than the massive pipeline mess I was using.

Comment: And, great info on FindAll. I am going to need to use this as an excuse to dig around in the documentation. I feel like maybe I will finally be able to look at the docs and know which approach to predicates to use now. Woot!